# Is there anyway to export/import all alfred configuration ?

Tags: configuration, dropbox, alfred

I want to export all alfred 3 configurations to hard driver, or import it from hard driver.

For some reason use DropBox to sync configurations is unavailable for me, so is there anyway to deal with it ?

Configurations include all item in preference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Sync Your Preferences

[image: Alfred 3 on macOS]

The *Advanced* tab is where you set the location to which *Alfred* preferences will be saved.  Whilst they recommend a cloud service, and in particular *Dropbox* (I've no idea why *Dropbox* would be especially superior), you can choose any cloud service you like (that has a locally accessible shared folder on your computer); or you can just choose an ordinary local folder that isn't stored in the cloud.

I, personally, use my iCloud folder to store the preferences in.

Just have a read of the description I've drawn a pink rectangle around, and make sure you understand what is happening.  But it's pretty straight forward.

### Importing Preferences

Generally, if your preferences are synced, they won't need to be re-imported.  But if you do need to for any reason, just locate the preferences file which looks like this:

[image: Alfred Preferences File]

and double-click.  It will automatically open in *Alfred* and the new preferences will take immediate effect.

Comment: It only works once then doesn't update again.

Comment: You need the Powerpack for this.

Comment: As of 2024-01-24 or earlier, double clicking the file results in a message `You cannot open an Alfred Preferences file directly.`

Comment: @jezmck I imagine it's less about the date you happen to attempt to open the file, but rather the version of Alfred you are using.  Thus, I recommend first discerning which version of Alfred your error pertains to, and, should you need to find out how to open its Preferences file, the Alfred forum would be one place to get the answer.  Let us know what you uncover.